# is it possible to call built-in Membership.CreateUser() function in a transaction in asp.net?

Tags: sql, function, call

is it possible to call built-in Membership.CreateUser() function in a transaction in asp.net?
if yes, then can the changes be rolled back if the transaction gets an error in next sql statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

https://pedroliska.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/calling-membership-createuser-with-db-transaction-support/

**Two options:**

1. Call the built-in stored procedure for user creation `aspnet_Membership_CreateUser` within your transaction.
2. Use the Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) via .NET’s TransactionScope class.